# Train arrival probability

Tags: probability

I must (probably) solve a problem of similar kind in order to enter university in my country:

> In a train station, between 8 and 10 in morning [why this time in the morning? Looks like a useless information to me], arrive on average 2 trains in a 20 minutes interval.
> Determine the probability that in 20 minutes:
>
> a) No trains arrive;
>
> b) Exactly one train arrives;
>
> c) At most 4 trains arrive
>
> z) [Added by me out of curiosity, not part of the original problem] How much must you wait on average before a train arrives?

I can solve this via computer simulation, getting the answers, respectively:

a) 0.13425

b) 0.27142

c) 0.94793

z) 597.64011 (seconds)

Sadly in the exam no programmable electronic device is allowed, I can only use non-programmable calculator, how to solve this problem by Mathematical reasoning instead of simulation?

[Here you can get the computer simulation and the problem statement in the original language (Italian)](https://codepaste.net/d865k1)

Comment: Note that in your simulation you assume that at most one train arrives in one second. You should check out the *Poisson distribution*

Comment: My guess is that questions (a)-(c) you are supposed to use a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=2$.  That would make the answer to (b) to be $P(X=1)=\dfrac{\lambda^1 e^{-\lambda}}{1!} \approx 0.27067$ and your simulation comes close

Comment: If you assume a memoryless Poisson process (forget timetables), then the answer to (z) would be $\frac{20}{2}=10$ minutes, i.e. $600$ seconds.  Again your simulation comes close

Comment: Why does it bother you that you're given information that technically is irrelevant? No problem in the real world that is worth solving will give you exactly the information you need and nothing else. Accepting that and learning to filter out such things without getting hung up on them is part of the skillset in the subject of mathematics.

Comment: @user133281 2 trains in one second has a probability of `train_probability_per_second ** 2` that is `2.7777777777777783 * 10 ** (-6)`  so it looks completely ignorable to me

Comment: It's true that it looks ignorable, but if you _don't_ ignore it, the numbers are (almost) possible to calculate by hand instead of by computer (you need to calculate powers of $e$, factorials and fractions).

Comment: @Arthur my question is exactly about how this is possible to calculate by hand instead of by computer, also by your reasoning because math is about exact solutions I should take into account 3 trains in a second, 4 trains in a second, 5 trains in a second and so on... up to infinity maybe?

Comment: Exactly. There is no reason (mathematical or physical) that two or more trains can't arrive within exactly the same second. The only limitation is that on average, there are six trains power hour. It might seem insurmountable, but you should google "poisson process" and see how it can be handled.

Comment: @Arthur So a full Math solution should take into account this limit even if it contributes so little to the end result? Must I do it because before doing it I cannot know by how much it contributes?

Comment: Yes and no. A full solution should take it into account, but that's not the reason we include those cases. I agree that for using a computer to calculate this, assuming that only one train arrives in a given second is a good approximation. However, if we drop that assumption, then some clever reasoning leads to a nice and easy-to-use formula. For instance, as said in a comment above, the probability of exactly one train arriving in a given $20$ minute period becomes $\frac{2e^{-2}}{1!}$, which is simple to calculate with a calculator.

Comment: @Arthur OK, so in your opinion does the question imply this assumption (no two trains can arrive in the same time-step (be it a second or a minute)) or is the problem more complex (it is be possible for two trains to arrive at the same time-step)? If the second case which procedure to follow to obtain a result by hand math calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the trains arrive *completely* independently of one another (this implies, for instance, that one train arriving within a specific second doesn't exclude another train arriving at the same second, and therefore, theoretically, any number of trains can arrive within any given second). In that case, what we have is a so-called *Poisson process*.

To get there, let's start with your second-division. If the trains truly cannot arrive within the same second, but are otherwise independent, then we can just look at the $1200$ $1$-second intervals in a $20$-minute period, and ask whether a train arrived or not. This would then give us a binomial distribution, with $n = 1200$, and expected value of $2$. That means that $p$, the probability of "success" (i.e. "a train arriving") for every given second is $\frac{2}{1200} = \frac{1}{600}$. For instance, our calculations for (b) would be
$$
P(1\text{ train}) = \binom{1200}1\left(\frac{1}{600}\right)^1\left(\frac{599}{600}\right)^{1199}
$$
and in general, for $k$ trains we get
$$
P(k\text{ trains}) = \binom{1200}k\left(\frac{1}{600}\right)^k\left(\frac{599}{600}\right)^{1200 - k}
$$
Now, let's divide it even smaller. Say we divide it into *milliseconds* instead. Then we have new binomial distribution with $n = 1\,200\,000$ and still with expectation value $2$, which means that our new $p$ becomes $\frac{1}{600\,000}$. Now the probability of exactly one train arriving becomes
$$
P(1\text{ train}) = \binom{1\,200\,000}1\left(\frac{1}{600\,000}\right)^1 \left(\frac{599\,999}{600\,000}\right)^{1\,199\,999}
$$
and in general, for $k$ trains
$$
P(k\text{ trains}) = \binom{1\,200\,000}k\left(\frac{1}{600\,000}\right)^k \left(\frac{599\,999}{600\,000}\right)^{1\,200\,000-k}
$$
Continuing this way, we can, with a small leap of faith, see that the true distribution if the trains are completely independent from one another, is
$$
P(k \text{ trains}) = \lim_{n \to \infty}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^k\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)^{n-k}
$$
This turns out to become $\dfrac{2^k\cdot e^{-2}}{k!}$, which is a simple enough formula that you can calculate it with most calculators. This is called the Poisson distribution (note that the $2$ that is raised to the $k$-th power and the $2$ in the exponential both come from the $2$ trains you expect within a $20$-minute period).